# Close box on old questions still says "Off-topic because...too old to migrate"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, off-topic, close-dialog

I was voting to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919231/finding-the-intersection-of-two-arrays) as off topic because the OP doesn't show any effort at solving it himself, when I noticed that next to the off topic title, it still says "too old to migrate". That *made* sense when off topic meant it belonged on another site, but now it doesn't.

Can we change this to just show that it can't be migrated? Like graying out the selection to migrate?

Obligatory screenshot:
[image: oh me gos! etz uh skweenshot! et evun hez fwee hen cirkel!]

Comment: I'd suggest maybe moving that note to the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" option that pops up *after* off-topic is selected.

Comment: @Jim: But if it's too old to migrate, that option doesn't appear in the secondary list.

Comment: Questions are still migrated through the "off-topic" close reason, so if it can't be migrated, that text is put there to indicate such.  If you think it should be different or could be made better somehow, then you might modify your question to make that suggestion.  If you do, feel free to retag as "feature-request".

Comment: @animuson Perhaps it could appear as unselectable, or in some other way indicate that migrating questions is normally an option, but not this time.

Comment: @Jim edited to reflect your idea.

Comment: *"I was voting to close [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919231/finding-the-intersection-of-two-arrays) as off topic because it looks like homework"* That just sounds totally ridiculous.

Comment: @CodeGray got anything better? That's how off-topic is defined now sadly...

Comment: I disagree. Homework questions are still not off-topic.

Comment: @CodeGray does the OP provide any effort at solving the problem? No. He dumps some code (albeit down to the right function) and asks how to do something.

Comment: @CodeGray edited. My reasoning with all the horrid questions here lately has led me to see "how do I do this" questions as homework. Flawed I know.

Comment: You've got his handle wrong, @Coly.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm on mobile where there aren't popups :/

Comment: If a question is too old to migrate, but it is off-topic because there is now a more suitable SE network site, then there should at least be an option to close the question for that reason.